# Issues with Temp Profile

Tags: windows-8.1, user-profiles

I recently had to restore a laptop that was set up incorrectly. After the restore the machine had the trust relationship issue with the domain.

I took the machine off the domain and when I came to add it back I realised that the machine was not given the right name so I changed it.

The user I am having the issue with was logged in fine under the old name but now under the new name I am constantly met with a temp profile when using his credentials.

I deleted his profile in the C Drive aswell as the TEMP profile and tried to start over with the users profile but I am still getting temporary profiles with his credentials.

when I log in with an admin account it is fine... how can I restore my users network profile as apposed to being logged in with a local profile?

Comment: Sounds like a reason to just reimage the machine

Comment: Reinstall? yeah I have started that process off now but I would like to know a fix for this problem without wasting time reinstalling a machine... I will put the make and model of the machine in question for review by someone if it helps.

Comment: It won't help because this is a domain configuration problem.  The only thing important is that its running Windows 8.1

Comment: @Ramhound the only reason why I would've put the specs is because I have witnessed this same problem on machines of the same description and on no other type of machine on my network.